# sklearn random forest: .oob_score_ too low?

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, random-forest, cross-validation

I was searching for applications for random forests, and I found the following knowledge competition on Kaggle:

https://www.kaggle.com/c/forest-cover-type-prediction.

Following the advice at

https://www.kaggle.com/c/forest-cover-type-prediction/forums/t/8182/first-try-with-random-forests-scikit-learn,

I used **`sklearn`** to build a random forest with 500 trees.

The **`.oob_score_`** was ~2%, but the score on the holdout set was ~75%.

There are only seven classes to classify, so 2% is really low.  I also consistently got scores near 75% when I cross validated.

Can anyone explain the discrepancy between the **`.oob_score_`** and the holdout/cross validated scores? I would expect them to be similar.

There's a similar question here:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95818/what-is-a-good-oob-score-for-random-forests

Edit: I think it might be a bug, too.

The code is given by the original poster in the second link I posted.  The only change is that you have to set **`oob_score = True`** when you build the random forest.

I didn't save the cross validation testing I did, but I could redo it if people need to see it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics, not programming.

Comment: Well, it kind of sounds like a bug :-/. Can you post your code somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

### Q: Can anyone explain the discrepancy ...

**A:** The **`sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier`** object and it's observed **`.oob_score_`** attribute value is not a bug-related issue.

First, **`RandomForest`**-based predictors **`{ Classifier | Regressor }`** belong to rather specific corner of so called ensemble methods, so be informed, that **typical** approaches, incl. **Cross-Validation, do not work the same way** as for other AI/ML-learners.

**RandomForest** ["inner"-logic works heavily with **RANDOM-PROCESS**](http://stat.ethz.ch/education/semesters/ss2012/ams/slides/v10.2.pdf), by which the Samples ( DataSET **`X`** ) with known  `y == { labels` ( for Classifier ) `| targets` ( for Regressor ) `}`, gets split throughout the forest generation, where trees get **bootstrapped** by RANDOMLY split DataSET into part, that the tree can see and a part, the tree will not see ( forming thus an inner-oob-subSET ).

Besides other effects on a sensitivity to overfitting et al, the **RandomForest** ensemble does not have a need to get Cross-Validated, because it does not over-fit by design. Many papers and also **[Breiman's](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/APR07.pdf)** (Berkeley) empirical proofs have provided support for such statement, as they brought evidence, that CV-ed predictor will have the same **`.oob_score_`**

```
import sklearn.ensemble
aRF_PREDICTOR = sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor( n_estimators                = 10,           # The number of trees in the forest.
                                                        criterion                   = 'mse',        # { Regressor: 'mse' | Classifier: 'gini' }
                                                        max_depth                   = None,
                                                        min_samples_split           = 2,
                                                        min_samples_leaf            = 1,
                                                        min_weight_fraction_leaf    = 0.0,
                                                        max_features                = 'auto',
                                                        max_leaf_nodes              = None,
                                                        bootstrap                   = True,
                                                        oob_score                   = False,        # SET True to get inner-CrossValidation-alike .oob_score_ attribute calculated right during Training-phase on the whole DataSET
                                                        n_jobs                      = 1,            # { 1 | n-cores | -1 == all-cores }
                                                        random_state                = None,
                                                        verbose                     = 0,
                                                        warm_start                  = False
                                                        )
aRF_PREDICTOR.estimators_                             # aList of <DecisionTreeRegressor>  The collection of fitted sub-estimators.
aRF_PREDICTOR.feature_importances_                    # array of shape = [n_features]     The feature importances (the higher, the more important the feature).
aRF_PREDICTOR.oob_score_                              # float                             Score of the training dataset obtained using an out-of-bag estimate.
aRF_PREDICTOR.oob_prediction_                         # array of shape = [n_samples]      Prediction computed with out-of-bag estimate on the training set.
    
aRF_PREDICTOR.apply(         X )                      # Apply trees in the forest to X, return leaf indices.
aRF_PREDICTOR.fit(           X, y[, sample_weight] )  # Build a forest of trees from the training set (X, y).
aRF_PREDICTOR.fit_transform( X[, y] )                 # Fit to data, then transform it.
aRF_PREDICTOR.get_params(          [deep] )           # Get parameters for this estimator.
aRF_PREDICTOR.predict(       X )                      # Predict regression target for X.
aRF_PREDICTOR.score(         X, y[, sample_weight] )  # Returns the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction.
aRF_PREDICTOR.set_params(          **params )         # Set the parameters of this estimator.
aRF_PREDICTOR.transform(     X[, threshold] )         # Reduce X to its most important features.
```

One shall be also informed, that default values do not serve best, the less serve well under any circumstances. One shall take care to the problem-domain so as to propose a reasonable set of **`ensemble`** parametrisation, before moving further.

---

### Q: What is a good .oob_score_ ?

### A: .oob_score_ is RANDOM! .  .  .  .  . . .....Yes, it *MUST* ( be random )

While this sound as a provocative epilogue, do not throw your hopes away.
RandomForest ensemble is a great tool. Some problems may come with categoric-values in features ( DataSET `X` ), however the costs of processing the ensemble are still adequate once you need not struggle with neither bias nor overfitting. **That's great, isn't it?**

Due to the need to be able to reproduce same results on subsequent re-runs, it is a recommendable practice to (re-)set **`numpy.random`** & **`.set_params( random_state = ... )`** to a know-state before the RANDOM-PROCESS ( embedded into every bootstrapping of the RandomForest ensemble ). Doing that, one may observe a "de-noised" progression of the **`RandomForest`**-based predictor in a direction of better **`.oob_score_`** rather due to *truly* *improved* predictive powers introduced by more ensemble members ( **`n_estimators`** ), less constrained tree-construction ( `max_depth`, `max_leaf_nodes` et al ) and not just stochastically by just "better luck" during the RANDOM-PROCESS of how to split the DataSET...

Going closer towards better solutions typically involves more trees into the ensemble ( RandomForest decisions are based on a majority vote, so 10-estimators is not a big basis for making good decisions on highly complex DataSETs ). Numbers above 2000 are not uncommon. One may iterate over a range of sizings ( with RANDOM-PROCESS kept under state-full control ) to demonstrate the ensemble "improvements".

If initial values of **`.oob_score_`** fall somewhere around about 0.51 - 0.53 your ensemble is **1% - 3% better than a RANDOM-GUESS**

Only after you make your ensemble-based predictor to something better, you may move into some additional tricks on feature engineering et al.

```
aRF_PREDICTOR.oob_score_    Out[79]: 0.638801  # n_estimators =   10
aRF_PREDICTOR.oob_score_    Out[89]: 0.789612  # n_estimators =  100
```

Comment: Thanks.  My point was that the oob_score was extremely low relative to the CV or holdout score.  In any case, I can't reproduce the issue any more.  All the scores are now similar.

Comment: Btw, what `scikit-learn` version did you work with? Pre-`0.15` had rather different inner workings. With the recent `0.16.1-stable` ( and hopefully `0.17.0-wet-ink` too ) your `.oob_score_` calls on forests with a few hundreds of trees shall be reasonable.

Comment: I don't remember which version I was using at the time I made the post.  I was probably close to the most recent version at the time.  I re-ran my tests using 0.16.1.

Comment: Ok. Glad to know. How many examples do you have in the DataSET? There is a rather strong exception in RandomForest-learners, that their .oob_score_ for CV limits to an .oob_score_ of the whole DataSET. Which makes feasible to incorporate the whole DataSET into training phase and internal mechanics handle the OOB samples right through the randomised splits of the DataSET used for the very tree-generation. More on that in academia papers and Scikit-learn documentation. Still experimenting with depth of trees and max number of parameters, as noted on Kaggle about keeping "diversity" of trees high

Comment: The "LOW" value of .oob_score_ might get re-tested via an experiment to use Anaconda/conda package-manager to create a separate python environment with scikit-learn { 0.13 | 0.14 | ... } and if the low score proves to be release-bound, you got the issue trouble-shooted to the roots

Comment: *"If .oob_score_ ~0.51 - 0.53 your ensemble is 1% - 3% better than a random guess* That's not correct, he stated it's a seven-class classification problem. Random guess would be ~0.14. An oob_score of 0.02 is far worse than random.