# Scikit-learn RandomForestClassifier() feature selection, just select the train set?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I'm using scikit-learn for machine learning.

I have 800 samples with 2048 features, therefore I want to reduce my features to get hopefully a better accuracy.

It is a multiclass problem (class 0-5), and the features consists of **`1`**'s and **`0`**'s:  `[1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0....,0]`

I'm using the ensemble method, **`RandomForestClassifier()`**.

**Should I** just feature select the training data **?**

**Is it enough** if I'm using this code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, y, test_size = .3 )

clf = RandomForestClassifier( n_estimators = 200,
                              warm_start   = True,
                              criterion    = 'gini',
                              max_depth    = 13
                              )

clf.fit( X_train, y_train ).transform( X_train )

predicted       = clf.predict( X_test )
expected        = y_test
confusionMatrix = metrics.confusion_matrix( expected, predicted )
```

Cause the accuracy didn't get higher. Is everything ok in the code or am I doing something wrong?

I'll be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Would you mind, Herb, posting also values you get from **`sklearn.__version__`**, and also from `clf.set_params( oob_score = True ).fit( ... ).oob_score_` for `( X_train, y_train )` resp. **`( X, y )`** ? Thanks.

Comment: Also may check >>> http://stackoverflow.com/a/30471026/3666197 -- namely the **Breiman's (Berkeley)** papers on bootstrap-aggregation method, that **by design avoids overfitting artifacts** and a proven limit theorem on `.fit( X_test, y_test ).oob_score_` lim-> `.fit( X, y ).oob_score_` & other important things, that are specific for RF-based ensemble methods. The goal to solve a problem inside a **2048D**-binary-`{0|1}`-space does not suffer from "dimensionality" per se. Deeper look on RF's strengths (probably with limited `max_depth` but **increased "forest width" ( diversity )** ) can help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your question correctly so I'll answer to what I thought I understood =)

First, reducing the dimension of your features (from 2048 to 500 e.g.) might not provide you with better results. It all depends on the capacity of your model to catch the geometry of your data. You can get much better results for example with a linear model if you reduce dimension through non-linear methods that would catch a particular geometry and 'linearize' it, instead of directly using this linear model on the raw data. But this is because your data would intrinsicaly be non-linear and the linear model is not good therefore in the original space to catch this geometry (think of a circle in 2D).

In the code you gave, you did not reduce dimension though, you splitted the data into two dataset (feature dimension is the same, 2048, only the number of samples changed). Training on a smaller dataset most of the time results in worst accuracy (data = information, when you leave some out you lose information). But splitting data allows you to test overfitting in particular, which is very impotant. But once the best parameters chosen (see cross-validation) you should learn on all the data you have!

Given your 0.7*800=560 samples, I think a depth of 13 is pretty big and you might overfit. You may want to play with this parameter first if you want to improve your accuracy!

Answer (score 1):

1) Often reducing the features space does not help with accuracy, and using a regularized classifier leads to better results.
2) To do feature selection, you need two methods: one to reduce the set of features, another that does the actual supervised task (classification here).

Have you tried just using the standard classifiers? Clearly you tried the RF, but I'd also try a linear method like LinearSVC/LogisticRegression or a kernel SVC.

If you want to do feature selection, what you need to do is something like this:

feature_selector = LinearSVC(penalty='l1')  #or maybe start with SelectKBest()
feature_selector.train(X_train, y_train)

X_train_reduced = feature_selector.transform(X_train)
X_test_reduced = feature_selector.transform(X_test)

classifier = RandomForestClassifier().fit(X_train_reduced, y_train)

prediction = classifier.predict(X_test_reduced)

Or you use a pipeline, as here: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/feature_selection/feature_selection_pipeline.html
Maybe we should add a version without the pipeline to the examples?

[cross-posted from the mailing list where this was originally asked]

Answer (score 0):

Dimensionality reduction or feature selection is definitely advisable if you have more features than samples. You could look into [Principal Component Analysis](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) and other modules in `sklearn.decomposition` to reduce the number of features. There is also a useful section on [Feature Selection](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) in the scikit-learn documentation.

After fitting `sklearn.decomposition.PCA`, you could inspect the `explained_variance_ratio_` to determine an advisable number of features (`n_components`) to reduce to (the point of PCA here is to find a reduced number of features that captures most of the variance in your original feature space). Some might like to retain features that have a cumulative `explained_variance_ratio_` above 0.9, 0.95 etc, some like to drop features beyond which the `explained_variance_ratio_` drops suddenly. Then refit the `PCA` with the `n_components` you like, `transform` your `X_train` and `X_test`, and fit your classifier as above.